# ubuntu terminal

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

How can I scroll up or pause the terminal so I can read text before it goes too far up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hold down shift and use Page up and Page down to scroll.

You can also pipe the results to `less` (eg `ls -al | less`) or send a copy of the output to a text file with `tee` (eg `ls -al | tee filelist.txt`).

Answer (score 0):

You can temporarily pause your program by pressing `Ctrl-Z`.  This will put your program to sleep, obviously stopping any output.  The you can bring it back to the foreground with `fg`.

Answer (score 0):

Often <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd> can be used to [pause/resume terminal output](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XON/XOFF).

Comment: caveat: Ctrl-S is usually used in bash readline as 'forward-search-history'.  This may or may not work.

Comment: @Rich: When a foreground process is running, `readline` is inactive and the terminal is reconfigured to pause on `^S`.

Comment: Thanks @grawity.  Maybe it's different in Konsole, because I get search instead of XOFF.  I'll test more, thank you.

Comment: @Rich: The terminal emulator doesn't matter.